# Determine year quarter from specific date XSL

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I need a function to determine which year quarter a date belongs to.
I found an Excel function and tried to apply the same logic in xsl but it does not work

```
<xsl:function name="bi:Quarter">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quarter"><xsl:value-of select="round((((month-from-date($value)-1) mod 3)+1))"/></xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$quarter"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an example of your input, and indicate if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as it seems, you are using XSLT 2.0, you can calculate the quarter of a date using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ceiling(month-from-date($your-date) div 3)" />
```

**Note**: $your-date must be an instance of xs:date.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried something similar but it's not working as expected.
For example, for month 7 (2nd quarter) it would retrieve quarter 3 rounding up with the ceiling function.

Comment: @Gerardo Unless you are using a private fiscal year, July is the first month of the 3rd quarter.

Comment: You're right :) My bad.
Thanks Michael, I made a wrong calc. I will use that one.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for a variant that works with .NET (which doesn't support XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="ceiling(ms:format-date($your-date, 'M') div 3)"/>
```

I'm really bad in XSLT and I might be missing something, but for my case it worked perfectly.